# Свойству объекта класса не присваивается значение внутри функции

Tags: c++

Имею следующую функцию внутри класса:

```
int Load(const char* Filename, int Numberobject2, int Append2)
{
    int Namesize=0;
    FILE *File;
    File = fopen(Filename,"rb");
    fseek(File, 3*sizeof(int)+sizeof(long double)*8*Numberobject2+Append2,SEEK_SET);

    fread(&this->Mass,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    std::cout<<"M "<<this->Mass<<std::endl;
    fread(&this->Radius,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    std::cout<<"R "<<this->Radius<<std::endl;
    fread(&this->Position.X,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    fread(&this->Position.Y,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    fread(&this->Position.Z,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    std::cout<<"Position "<<"X: "<<this->Position.X<<" Y: "<<this->Position.Y<<" Z: "<<this->Position.Z<<std::endl;

    fread(&this->Speed.X,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    fread(&this->Speed.Y,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    fread(&this->Speed.Z,sizeof(long double),1,File);
    std::cout<<"Speed "<<"X: "<<this->Speed.X<<" Y: "<<this->Speed.Y<<" Z: "<<this->Speed.Z<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    fclose(File);

    return Namesize;

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в результате её выполнения объекту класса не присваиваются значения `Position.X`, `Position.Y`, `Position.Z`, а также и `Speed.X`, `Speed.Y`, `Speed.Z`, хоть и при выполнении функции их значения выводятся на экран консоли. При этом `Mass` и `Radius` значения присваиваются нормально.

Как исправить код так, чтобы все значения присваивались нормально и почему так происходит?

Вызов функции Load() (в контексте):

```
FILE *File;
File=fopen("save.dat","rb");

fread(&Countobjects,sizeof(int),1,File);
fread(&Totalsteps,sizeof(int),1,File);
fread(&Totaltime,sizeof(int),1,File);
Obj->Zeroing(true);
fclose(File);

std::cout<<"Countobjects: "<<Countobjects<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Totalsteps: "<<Totalsteps<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Totaltime: "<<Totaltime<<std::endl;


for (int i=0;i<Countobjects; i++)
{
    *Sizenames+=Obj->Load("save.dat", i,*Sizenames);
    Obj->Zeroing(true);
    Object.push_back(*Obj);
    Object[i].Getinfo();
}

delete Sizenames;
```

Объявления `Position` и `Speed`:

```
Vector Position;
Vector Speed;
```

Класс `Vector`:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    long double X;
    long double Y;
    long double Z;
    long double Num;

    Vector (int a,int b,int c)
    {
        X=(long double)a;
        Y=(long double)b;
        Z=(long double)c;
    }
    Vector()
    {
        X=0;
        Y=0;
        Z=0;
    }

    void Zeroing()
    {
        this->X=0;
        this->Y=0;
        this->Z=0;
        this->Num=0;
    }
};
```

Вывод на консоли:

Countobjects: 2

Totalsteps: 1000

Totaltime:1000

// Вывод функции Load()

M 1e+024

R 1e+006

Position x:6.41821e-005 Y: 6.41821e-005 Z: -6.41821e-005

Speed X

//Вывод функции Getinfo()

Name is
Mass: 1e+024

Radius: 1e+006

Position X: 0 Y: 0 Z: 0

Speed:          Number: 0 X:0 Y:0 Z:0

Acceleration    Number: 0 X:0 Y:0 Z:0

Force:          Number: 0 X:0 Y:0 Z:0

Далее идёт почти то же самое со вторым объектом.

Comment: «в результате её выполнения объекту класса не присваиваются значения Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z» Это невозможно. С вас пруфы.

Comment: 1) дайте определение типа `Position`, и как он объявлен внутри класса, 2) покажите, как вы вызываете функцию `Load`, 3) проверьте возвращаемое значение `fread` (вы почему-то его игнорируете).

Comment: fread в 6 случаях вернуло 1.

Comment: private:: Vector Position; Vector Speed; Сам класс вектор: class Vector
{
public:
    long double X;
    long double Y;
    long double Z;
    long double Num;

    Vector (int a,int b,int c)
    {
        X=(long double)a;
        Y=(long double)b;
        Z=(long double)c;
    }
    Vector()
    {
        X=0;
        Y=0;
        Z=0;
    }

    void Zeroing()
    {
        this->X=0;
        this->Y=0;
        this->Z=0;
        this->Num=0;
    }

};

Comment: Вы бы лучше поместили эту информацию в вопрос (видите ссылку «править»?). Здесь её невозможно отформатировать.

Comment: Пруфы. Каким образом?

Comment: Ну, минимальный компилируемый пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Что вы вызываете, что выдаётся, и почему вы считаете, что это неправильно.

Comment: Просто результат вывода на консоли?

Comment: Например, вывод на консоли.

Comment: Смотрите, у вас тут `Object.push_back(*Obj);`. А есть ли у вас конструктор копирования?

Comment: Ещё: у вас в коде `*Sizenames+=Obj->Load("save.dat", i,*Sizenames); Obj->Zeroing(true);`. А не затираете ли вы при этом данные?

Comment: Да, так и оказалось.

Comment: Ну вот и хорошо, одной загадкой меньше.